# Set proxy as an environment variable in Helm 3

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

ı would like to set proxy as an env variable in deployment.yaml which I created via Helm v3.What should be the correct format to add env in helm template and meanwhile is there any way to pass this value in values.yaml?

```
  - env:
  - name: "HTTP_PROXY"
    value: "http://<user>:<password>@<ip_addr>:<port>"




    containers:
            - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
              securityContext:
                {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
              image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
              imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
              ports:
                - name: http
                  containerPort: 8080
                  protocol: TCP
              resources:
                {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928819/how-to-pull-environment-variables-with-helm-charts is that  the info you've been looking for?

Comment: yes that is what I want.. Thanks nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into consideration that Helm's syntax has been discussed a few times on Stack, I'm going just to sum it up in order to have less orphaned questions and post it as a community wiki, because I didn't do much here.

---

As it was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928819/how-to-pull-environment-variables-with-helm-charts), there are a few possible ways to add `env`'s.

**Way 1**. *Proper way of doing that (with secret).*

As you don't want to expose the data, so it's better to have it saved as secret in kubernetes.

First of all, add all the needed lines in your `Values` file, so that these values can be set from outside.

Example:

```
username: root
password: password
```

Then, add a `secret.yaml` file inside your `template` folder and copy needed data into that file.

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-auth
data:
  password: {{ .Values.password | b64enc }}
  username: {{ .Values.username | b64enc }}
```

Now tweak your deployment yaml template and make changes in `env` section, like this (of course you can combine envs in a way you need):

```
spec:
  restartPolicy: Always
   containers:
     - name: sample-app
       image: "sample-app:latest"
       imagePullPolicy: Always
         env:          
           - name: "USERNAME"
             valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
               key:  username
               name: {{ .Release.Name }}-auth
           - name: "PASSWORD"
             valueFrom:
               secretKeyRef:
                 key:  password
                 name: {{ .Release.Name }}-auth
```

---

**Way 2**. *`export` the variable and use it while running `helm install`*.

Before that, you have to modify your chart so that the value can be `set` while installation.

If you have modified your template correctly for `--set` flag,
you can set this using environment variable.

```
$ export USERNAME=root-user
```

Now use this variable while running helm install,

```
$ helm install --set username=$USERNAME ./mychart
```

If you run this `helm install` in `dry-run` mode, you can verify the changes,

```
$ helm install --dry-run --set username=$USERNAME --debug ./mychart
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '44937'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:44937"

[debug] Original chart version: ""
[debug] CHART PATH: /home/maruf/go/src/github.com/the-redback/kubernetes-yaml-drafts/helm-charts/mychart

NAME:   irreverant-meerkat
REVISION: 1
RELEASED: Fri Apr 20 03:29:11 2018
CHART: mychart-0.1.0
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
username: root-user

COMPUTED VALUES:
password: password
username: root-user

HOOKS:
MANIFEST:

---
# Source: mychart/templates/secret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: irreverant-meerkat-auth
data:
  password: password
  username: root-user
---
# Source: mychart/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: irreverant-meerkat
  labels:
    app: irreverant-meerkat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: irreverant-meerkat
      labels:
        app: irreverant-meerkat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: irreverant-meerkat
        image: alpine
        env:
        - name: "USERNAME"
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key:  username
              name: irreverant-meerkat-auth
        - name: "PASSWORD"
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key:  password
              name: irreverant-meerkat-auth

        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: irreverant-meerkat
```

You can see that the data of username in secret has changed to `root-user`.

[this example](https://github.com/the-redback/kubernetes-yaml-drafts/tree/master/helm-charts/mychart) has been added into github repo.

There is also some discussion in [kubernetes/helm](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm) repo regarding this. You can see [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/944) to know about all other ways to use environment variables.

---

Way 3. *Hardcode values **directly** in Yaml (quicker but not that secure/easy to maintain)*.

```
   spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
            - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
              securityContext:
                {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
              image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
              imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
              ports:
                - name: http
                  containerPort: 8080
                  protocol: TCP
              resources:
                {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
              env:
                - name: "HTTP_PROXY"
                  value: "http://<user>:<password>@<ip_addr>:<port>"
```

Comment: for way 3, is there any way to use go template? Such as name: {{ .Values.proxyname }} ?