# Helm, create env var with image tag value

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-helm

I'm fairly new to helm as I use charts created by other ppl for our applications and I'm trying to do something that I suppose is kinda easy but couldn't manage to find how to. Basically I want to pass application version to my react app. Based on the few information I found, here is what I came up with

```
image:
    tag: 0.2.6
extraEnv:
  - name: REACT_APP_APP_VERSION
    value: {image.tag}
```

thx in advance

Comment: See if you can find any solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928819/how-to-pull-environment-variables-with-helm-charts

Answer (score 0):

I assume the code you sent is your `values.yaml`. Then, the first part is correct.

```
image:
    tag: 0.2.6
```

Now, you don't specify variables passed to pod in `values.yaml`, but in your `templates/*` files. For example, to pass an variable to your pod, you can use the following code:

```
env:
  - name: REACT_APP_APP_VERSION
    value: "{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
```

Check [this](https://github.com/hazelcast/charts/blob/master/stable/hazelcast/templates/statefulset.yaml#L113) for the complete example.

Note that you cannot use values from `values.yaml` inside `values.yaml`. So the code you sent won't work. That is because, the `values.yaml` file itself is not evaluated.

Comment: Actually we have a values.yaml that contains values that are identical to every env. Then we have have an override values for each env and this is where I have both image.tag and REACT_APP_APP_VERSION var.

I guess it's impossible to achieve what I wanna do without major conf changes then.

Thx for you help

Comment: you actually can use templates in values.yaml and call `tpl` function for values in your chart template

Answer (score 0):

From [Documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function)

> The `tpl` function allows developers to evaluate strings as templates inside a template. This is useful to pass a template string as a value to a chart or render external configuration files. Syntax: `{{ tpl TEMPLATE_STRING VALUES }}`

You will have something similar to

**values.yaml**

```
image:
  repository: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
  tag: "latest"

extraEnv: "{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
```

**pod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
    env:
    - name: REACT_APP_APP_VERSION
      value: {{ tpl .Values.extraEnv . }}
```

helm template output for pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: "k8s.gcr.io/busybox:latest"
    env:
    - name: REACT_APP_APP_VERSION
      value: latest
```

Comment: What will be the resultant value for `REACT_APP_APP_VERSION` in pod.yaml?