# Modifying Airflow Helm chart values

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, airflow

I want to deploy airflow in Openshift.

I am using this values.yaml: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/airflow/values.yaml

I want to clone my dag files from the Bitbucket repository of my company.

I am modifying the /values.yaml to achieve that:

```
  dags:
    ## Enable in order to download DAG files from git repositories.
    ##
    enabled: true
    repositories:
      - repository: 
        branch: master
        name: dags
        path: docker-image/dags
```

in which part should I insert the info about the secrets in this values.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `values.yaml` file should have `git` at the beggining:

```
git:
  dags:
    ## Enable in order to download DAG files from git repositories.
    ##
    enabled: true
    repositories:
      - repository: 
        branch: master
        name: dags
        path: docker-image/dags
```

I assume you have a private repository and you want `airflow` to access it.
As you can see in the [Bitnami Apache Airflow Helm chart documentation](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/airflow#load-dag-files):

> If you use a private repository from GitHub, a possible option to clone the files is using a Personal Access Token and using it as part of the URL: https://USERNAME:PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY

It's about `GitHub` but I belive it also works with `Bitbucket`.

Personal access token can be used in `Bitbucket Data Center` and `Server`. You can find out how to create it in this [Personal access tokens documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html).

**NOTE:** If you use `Bitbucket Cloud` it is not possible to create personal access token but you can create [app password](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/) instead ( look at [Personal Access Token for Bitbucket Cloud?](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Personal-Access-Token-for-Bitbucket-Cloud/qaq-p/677663)).
I have `Bitbucket Cloud` and tested this scenario with the app password and it works as expected.

Comment: is it possible to use this Personal token as a environment variable from Openshift?

Comment: If you mean system environment variables then you can find helpful information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49930497/14801225).
If you mean Openshift environment variables (`oc set env`) , I don't think so, but unfortunately I'm not an expert in Openshift.