# How to override helm environment variables through CLI?

Tags: yaml, environment-variables, command-line-interface, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-deployment

I am using helm environment variables to override some of my spring boot application.yaml config and its working perfectly fine.

```
helm install deploy-name-1 mychartname --values=.helm/deployment/values.yaml
```

values.yaml

```
env:
  - name: WORD
    value: hello
```

On executing helm install command, I can see the right WORD being picked up during helm deployment that's all good.

However I would like to override the value of this environment variable "WORD" through helm install command on CLI. On trying I am facing the following error...

Command (taking from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928819/how-to-pull-environment-variables-with-helm-charts)):

```
helm install deployment2 mychartname --values=.helm/deployment/values.yaml --set env.WORD=tree
```

Error

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not map[string]interface {}

goroutine 1 [running]:
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/strvals.(*parser).key(0xc0004eff60, 0xc000538840, 0x1592d34, 0x1838b20)
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/pkg/strvals/parser.go:211 +0xdf1
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/strvals.(*parser).parse(0xc0004eff60, 0xc000538840, 0x0)
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/pkg/strvals/parser.go:133 +0x3f
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/strvals.ParseInto(0xc0000b60c0, 0x23, 0xc000538840, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/pkg/strvals/parser.go:70 +0xc5
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/cli/values.(*Options).MergeValues(0xc000080c60, 0xc0004efb40, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/pkg/cli/values/options.go:62 +0x232
main.newUpgradeCmd.func1(0xc0001e0500, 0xc0004ffd80, 0x2, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/cmd/helm/upgrade.go:82 +0x1fe
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc0001e0500, 0xc0004ffc80, 0x8, 0x8, 0xc0001e0500, 0xc0004ffc80)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.5/command.go:826 +0x467
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc00069d180, 0x1c2f380, 0xc000676160, 0xc0004586d0)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.5/command.go:914 +0x302
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.5/command.go:864
main.main()
        /home/circleci/helm.sh/helm/cmd/helm/helm.go:74 +0x1e9
```

deployment.yaml

```
...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Release.Name }}
          env:
            {{- range .Values.env }}
            - name: {{ .name }}
              value: {{ .value }}
            {{ end }}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`helm install --set`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set) option allows only basic path-based navigation and no more advanced query operations.  You can't look for the `env:` value with `name: WORD` and set the corresponding `value:`; all you can do is blindly set the first `env:` value.

```sh
helm install ... --set 'env[0].value=tree'
```

Rather than provide whole chunks of Kubernetes YAML through Helm values, it's more common to provide very specific settings; provide "the word" as configuration, rather than "a set of environment variables, which should include `WORD`".  Then you can straightforwardly override this specific thing.

```yaml
# templates/deployment.yaml
env:
  - name: WORD
    value: {{ .Values.word }}
```

```yaml
# values.yaml
word: hello
```

```sh
helm install ... --set word=tree
```

Comment: I m already using the template way u mentioned as a workaround but that involves amending the chart deployment for every variable. Its surprising that overriding helm environment variables by name from CLI is not supported! thanks for the clarification @David