# How to use environment/secret variable in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

In my helm chart, I have a few files that need credentials to be inputted
For example

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/test"
    auth="Container"
    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://{{ .Values.DB.host }}:{{ .Values.DB.port }};selectMethod=direct;DatabaseName={{ .Values.DB.name }};User={{ Values.DB.username }};Password={{ .Values.DB.password }}"
    />
```

I created a secret

```
Name: databaseinfo
   Data:
     username
     password
```

I then create environment variables to retrieve those secrets in my deployment.yaml:

```
env:
   - name: DBPassword
      valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        key: password
        name: databaseinfo
   - name: DBUser
       valueFrom:
       secretKeyRef:
         key: username
         name: databaseinfo
```

In my values.yaml or this other file, I need to be able to reference to this secret/environment variable. I tried the following but it does not work:
values.yaml

```
DB:
  username: $env.DBUser
  password: $env.DBPassword
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pull environment variables with Helm charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928819/how-to-pull-environment-variables-with-helm-charts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't pass variables from any template to `values.yaml` with helm. Just from `values.yaml` to the templates.

The answer you are seeking was posted by [mehowthe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3061469/mehowthe) :

deployment.yaml =

```
      env:          
        {{- range .Values.env }}
      - name: {{ .name }}
        value: {{ .value }}
     {{- end }}
```

values.yaml =

```
env:          
 - name: "DBUser"
   value: ""
 - name: "DBPassword"
   value: ""
```

then

`helm install chart_name --name release_name --set env.DBUser="FOO" --set env.DBPassword="BAR"`