# How to get jenkins variables to apply to Helm Chart

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm

I have a task, to get jenkins variables to apply to Helm chart value.

As I googled I recognized that I have to use secret part in k8s. We can not put variable's value into `value.yaml` file.

But for secret we have to put value into yaml file.

So how to get variable which we define in Jenkins job and put it to value of helm chart .

I think we have a solution for this but I didnot find out.

Appriciated your help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first use is to `--set`

```
export USERNAME=hello_user
```

this way you can overwrite the **values.yaml**

```
helm install --set username=$USERNAME [chart name] [chart path]
```

**Option : 2**

Inject file to Jenkin job

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-auth
stringData::
{{ .Files.Get "<chart_base_directory>/secrets" | indent 2 }}
```

You can also checkout this : [How to pull environment variables with Helm charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928819/how-to-pull-environment-variables-with-helm-charts)