# How to use github sha in helm chart?

Tags: github, github-actions, helm3

Im using github actions to deploy helm chart on eks. Here are steps:

1. Build the docker image
2. Push an image to ECR with git commit sha as tag.(Tag Ex: develop-21df036.... )
   So i want reference this tag in helm `values.yaml` here as

```
  repository:1234.dcr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/repo-name
  pullPolicy: Always
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: <tag>
```

so i tried with `develop-${{ github.sha }}` variable in tag, but this commit id will get once pushed to repo. Is there any other way to achieve this ?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pull environment variables with Helm charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928819/how-to-pull-environment-variables-with-helm-charts)

Comment: the environment variable is called `GITHUB_SHA`: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables

Comment: i used this values flag, values: image.tag=develop-${{ github.sha }}. Now this works. thanks @rethab