# How to pass parameterized variable into Chart.yml file for gitlab CI/CD?

Tags: gitlab, cicd

Currently my ***Chart.yml*** file looks like this:

```css
apiVersion: v2
name: test-api
version: 0.0.0
description: This is the job for testing 
sources:
- <gitlab project link>
maintainers:
- name: <Team Name>
  email: <Team email>
```

I would like to pass the variable from ***gitlab-ci.yml*** file for name of the Chart so
in my ***gitlab-ci.yml*** file, I have defined the variable name for Chart name something like this:

```css
   variables:
 CHART_NAME: 'test-api'
```

Next, I would like to pass the variable *CHART_NAME* from ***gitlab-ci.yml*** into ***Chart.yml*** file, so now the ***Chart.yml*** file looks like this:

```css
apiVersion: v2
name: ${CHART_NAME}
version: 0.0.0
description: This is the job for testing 
sources:
- <gitlab project link>
maintainers:
- name: <Team Name>
  email: <Team email>
```

but my pipeline failed while trying to publish the helm since my Chart.yml file is not able to read the value of variable CHART_NAME.

Can someone help If it is possible to pass the variable into Chart.yml file from gitlab-ci.yml?

Comment: GitLab ill set `CHART_NAME` as an environment variable, and you can follow [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49930497/10617695) to use it in Helm

Comment: @RaglandAsir I wanted to pass variable CHART_NAME into Chart.yml file. Do I have to tweak my job.yml file and make changes in ev section so that i can use it within Chart.yml file?