# Unable to add TLS certificate to GKE from Google Secret Manager

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, csi-driver, gcp-secret-manager

I have stored the SSL certificates in the GCP secret manager. I'm using Helm to deploy the application and configure the GKE ingress load balancer. I followed this [blog](https://akarshseggemu.medium.com/gcp-how-to-add-tls-certificate-to-gke-from-google-secret-manager-d3c468c34d64) to add TLS certificate to GKE from Google Secret Manager.

I stored the certificate in below format in Secret Manager

```
    -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----  
MIIC2DCCAcCgAwIBAgIBATANBgkqh ...
    -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  
MIIC2DCCAcCgAwIBAgIBATANBgkqh ...
    -----END CERTIFICATE----
```

In my helm deployment.yaml file, added the secret as volume

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test-frontend.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.global.namespace }}
  labels:
    {{- include "test-frontend.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "test-frontend.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "test-frontend.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ include "test-frontend.serviceAccountName" . }}
      automountServiceAccountToken: true
      securityContext:
        {{- toYaml .Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: {{ include "test-frontend.configMapName" . }}    
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
          volumeMounts:
          - name: ispsecret
            mountPath: /var/secret
      volumes:
        - name: testsecret
          csi:
            driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
            readOnly: true
            volumeAttributes:
              secretProviderClass: "test-tls"    

      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
```

and created test-secret-provider.yaml

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: test-tls
spec:
  provider: gcp
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: test-tls-csi
    type: kubernetes.io/tls
    data: 
    - objectName: "testcert.pem"
      key: tls.key
    - objectName: "testcert.pem"
      key: tls.crt
  parameters:
    secrets: |
      - resourceName: "projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/test_ssl_secret/versions/latest"
         fileName: "testcert.pem"
```

When I deploy the application using Helm, I'm getting below error in the GKE logs

> MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "testsecret" : rpc error: code =
> InvalidArgument desc = failed to mount secrets store objects for pod
> test/test-frontend-5f98895b4b-6zq9t, err: rpc error: code =
> InvalidArgument desc = failed to unmarshal secrets attribute: yaml:
> line 1: did not find expected key

How to fix this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the YAML indentation and format in the `parameters` section of your `SecretProviderClass` are correct. YAML is very sensitive to indentation, and even a small mistake can lead to parsing errors.
You would find a similar error in [`Azure/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure` issue 290](https://github.com/Azure/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/issues/290) for illustration.

```yaml
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: test-tls
spec:
  provider: gcp
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: test-tls-csi
    type: kubernetes.io/tls
    data: 
    - objectName: "testcert.pem"
      key: tls.key
    - objectName: "testcert.pem"
      key: tls.crt
  parameters:
    secrets: |
      - resourceName: "projects/${PROJECT_ID}/secrets/test_ssl_secret/versions/latest"
        fileName: "testcert.pem"
```

The `resourceName`/`fileName` in the `parameters` section are properly indented as a part of the list under `secrets`.

And [Online YAML Parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) seems to error on:

```yaml
volumeMounts:
            - name: testsecret
            mountPath: /var/secret
        volumes:
        - name: testsecret
        csi:
            driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
            readOnly: true
            volumeAttributes:
            secretProviderClass: "test-tls"
```

The error:

```
ERROR:

while parsing a block mapping
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 5:
        volumeMounts:
        ^
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "<unicode string>", line 4, column 11:
              volumes:
              ^
```

A better indentation:

```yaml
volumeMounts:
  - name: testsecret
    mountPath: /var/secret
volumes:
  - name: testsecret
    csi:
      driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
      readOnly: true
      volumeAttributes:
        secretProviderClass: "test-tls"
```

The `volumes` block was being indented in a way that made it appear as a continuation of the properties of `testsecret` under `volumeMounts`, which is not structurally valid.
Now, `volumeMounts` and `volumes` are at the same indentation level, indicating they are part of the same Kubernetes resource definition (e.g., a Pod spec).

---

```
rpc error: code = InvalidArgument 
desc = failed to mount secrets store objects for pod test/test-frontend-5f98895b4b-6zq9t, 
err: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument 
desc = failed to unmarshal secrets attribute: yaml: line 1: did not find expected key
```

Check also the logs for the CSI driver pods in your cluster. You can find the CSI driver pods in the `kube-system` namespace or another namespace if you have configured it differently. Look for any errors that mention issues with processing the `SecretProviderClass` or accessing the secrets from Google Secret Manager.

Your current error message suggests that there is a failure in parsing the `volumeAttributes` or similar configuration passed to the CSI driver, specifically indicating a problem with parsing or recognizing a key in the provided YAML configuration.

Check that:

- the `volumeAttributes` matches the expected keys and structure defined by your CSI driver and the `SecretProviderClass`. Verify that every key and value under `volumeAttributes` is expected and supported.
- the `secretProviderClass` value exactly matches the name of an existing `SecretProviderClass` in your cluster.
- the configuration within your `SecretProviderClass`correctly references the secret in the Secret Manager. Any discrepancy here, such as an incorrect `resourceName` or a misconfigured `secretObjects` section, can lead to errors.
- the format expected by the CSI driver is correct for the CSI convert them into Kubernetes secrets correctly ( a bit as in [`aws/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-aws` issue 77](https://github.com/aws/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-aws/issues/77)): review the `SecretProviderClass` YAML, specifically the `parameters.secrets` block, to make sure it correctly formats the reference to your secret in Google Secret Manager.

---

> In `SecretProviderClass` Yaml, under `parameters.secret` block, I'm passing GCP secret manager path `projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/test_ssl_secret/versions/latest` which contains `PROJECT_ID`.
>
> Will the YAML fetch the `PROJECT_ID`, or do I need to explicitly mention the `PROJECT ID` and does it related to permission issue accessing the GCP secret manager?

In the context of Kubernetes and [Helm](https://helm.sh/), environment variable placeholders like `$PROJECT_ID` are not automatically resolved within raw YAML files. For dynamic value substitution (e.g., inserting the `PROJECT_ID` into your YAML), you typically need to use a templating engine or pass these values in through a process that understands how to replace them. Helm, for example, uses template values from `values.yaml` and template functions to insert dynamic content into your YAML files before they are applied to the Kubernetes cluster.
See for instance: "[How to pull environment variables with Helm charts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64995041/6309)"

The "secret access permissions" error could indeed be related to a permissions issue if the Kubernetes cluster (specifically, the node pool's service account) does not have permission to access the Google Secret Manager secret.  Make sure the service account associated with your GKE nodes has the required roles/permissions (`secretmanager.versions.access`) to access secrets in Google Secret Manager.

However, the error message you shared suggests that the problem occurs earlier in the process, during the parsing of the YAML configuration, rather than at the point of accessing the secret in Secret Manager.

So make sure that the `PROJECT_ID` is correctly injected into your `SecretProviderClass` YAML. Since Helm is being used, you can utilize Helm's templating capabilities to achieve this:

```yaml
parameters:
  secrets: |
    - resourceName: "projects/{{ .Values.projectID }}/secrets/test_ssl_secret/versions/latest"
      fileName: "testcert.pem"
```

In the above snippet, `{{ .Values.projectID }}` is a Helm template directive that tells Helm to replace this placeholder with the value of `projectID` defined in your Helm chart's `values.yaml` file. You would need to make sure `values.yaml` (or whichever values file you are using) includes something like:

```yaml
projectID: your-gcp-project-id
```

The revised deployment YAML you have shared looks properly formatted regarding indentation and structure. The persistent error, "failed to unmarshal secrets attribute," points toward an issue with how the secrets data is formatted or interpreted rather than a straightforward syntax error in your YAML.
Considering the context of dynamic variable replacement discussed earlier, the error might be from an improperly formatted or unresolved `resourceName` in your `SecretProviderClass` configuration, if the dynamic substitution for `PROJECT_ID` was not effectively applied.