Helm: Set environment variables in values.yaml
We have a lot of key: value pairs, which we want to be set as environment variables (not Spring variables) for Java applications running in Kubernetes. Their names and amount varies among the applications, and their values are set differently for various environments.
Hence we would like to use the Helm values.yaml, values-dev.yaml, values-staging.yaml etc. files to manage the setting.
The solution should be so when a variable or its value changes, only the values-xxx.yaml files need to be changed, and nothing else.
The values.yaml looks like this:
env:
  VARIABLE_1: VALUE_1
  VARIABLE_2: VALUE_2
  VARIABLE_3: VALUE_3
  # many key-value pairs like this

EDIT:
This question asks about how to implement bulk setting of environment variables using values.yaml and deployment.yaml. The question referred in the comments How to pull environment variables with Helm charts asks something different, even if one of the answers suggests a solution very similar to mine. I would never have been able to search for the answer in the referred question. These questions are not duplicate.

Does this answer your question? How to pull environment variables with Helm charts

@Webber: Indeed one of the answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/60098256/2886891 mentioned the same solution, but the question was not exactly the same. They asked how to pull the value of two specific variables from local environment variables. My motivation was how to pull any amount of unknown variables from values.yaml. I think that although the two questions overlap, especially in their solution, they are not the same. Also notice that the accepted answer in your referred question is about something quite different - simply because the question was different.

The answer saying how helm charts work has 50 upvotes. The question doesn't have to be exactly the same if it is in principle the same. This question is asking what is explained perfectly fine in the official docs: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/
And I'd argue that the official docs are in fact a better place that offers a more complete and up-to-date set of ways of how to go about variables than this "solution". Hence I vote to close.

I was solving a specific problem. I didn't find any question like this. I had to compile my solution based on multiple sources. And isn't it normal, that the answers usually are in documentation, if you know exactly what you are searching for? Aren't many good answers in SO refer to the official documentation? Why does my Q&A bother you so much that you cannot leave it here for future reference, if someone else might search for the same I was struggling with? Does it sound too trivial for you so you cannot understand that it can be a problem for someone else?

I believe my argument already answers your question. I believe the argument about the official docs being a better resources than this is a fair one. To clarify: In this case I would rather land on the official docs than in this question and answer when coming from a search engine. That isn't always the case. Either way, it's a democratic system, more votes are needed. No need to make it personal.

To make the Kubernetes container properly set the system environment variables, the deployment.yaml should look like this:
...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: MY_CONTAINER_NAME
      ...
      env:
        - name: VARIABLE_1
          value: VALUE_1
        - name: VARIABLE_2
          value: VALUE_2
        - name: VARIABLE_3
          value: VALUE_3

So the problem is what template shall we put into deployment.yaml so it renders like above.
Using the Helm flow control and dictionary functions in deployment.yaml:
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.env }}
- name: {{ $key }}
  value: {{ $value | quote }}
{{- end }}

and having values.yaml like this:
env:
  VARIABLE_1: VALUE_1
  VARIABLE_2: VALUE_2
  VARIABLE_3: VALUE_3

it is rendered indeed as
- name: VARIABLE_1
  value: VALUE_1
- name: VARIABLE_2
  value: VALUE_2
- name: VARIABLE_3
  value: VALUE_3

Here is the solution in Helm Playground so you may further experiment with it.

Didn't know about the Helm Playground, thanks for sharing :-)
